# Backup QVD files every day & save three versions before removing the first generation

Tags: powershell

I have a few QlikView servers with alot of QVD files I need to backup.
The idea is to backup three generations, so lets say the app is named tesla.qvd.

Backing it up naming it like testa.qvd.2019-06.05 if the file was modified today.

Then it would backup a new one the next time it's modified/written to.

In total I would like to save two generations before the first one is removed.

This is for a windows 2012 server, using PS 4.0

```
#$RemotePath = "C:\qlikview Storage\privatedata\backup\"
$LocalPath = "C:\qlikview Storage\privatedata"
$nomatch = "*\backup\*"
$predetermined=[system.datetime](get-date)
$date= ($predetermined).AddDays(-1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")
Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem -File $localpath -Recurse |  Where {$_.FullName -notlike $nomatch} -Verbose ))
{
       Copy-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination "C:\qlikview Storage\privatedata\backup\$file.$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)"

}
```

The code above would back the files up with the dates as described in the text before the code.

It's proceeding from here thats my problem. 
I tried google and searching the forum.
I don't ask for someone to solve the whole issue I have.

But if you can help me out with which functions / what I should look on to get my end result it would help alot so I can proceed.

[image: In the picture you can see an example how the library looks after backup has been done. The lastwrite on the files would be same as date thou, this is fictionaly created for this question.]

In the picture you can see an example how the library looks after backup has been done. The lastwrite on the files would be same as date thou, this is fictionaly created for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the basename attribute of the files in the backup folder since you add a new extension to the files. It would look something like this:

```
# Group by basename and find groups with more then 2 backups
$Groups = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\qlikview Storage\privatedata\backup" | Group-Object basename | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 2}
foreach ($g in $Groups) {
    $g.Group  | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select -skip 2 | foreach {del $_.fullname -force}
}
```

Comment: Axel, interesting, I will make a test with it.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not do anything in the end, it accepts the code but the file remains.

Comment: What do you get when you run:
    Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\qlikview Storage\privatedata\backup"  | select basename, extension

Comment: Updated the answer. $g should be $g.Group

Comment: Did some more modifications, but now everything works like a charm, thank you.